# js canvas white line between 2 objects

Tags: javascript, canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlrFm.png)I'm having a problem with my graphic objects on canvas.
My Rectangle consists out of two triangles. But when I fill the path of both triangles a little white line in between of them occurs. It's on the diagonal of the rectangle.

```
s.initQuadrangle(new Point3D([100, 100, 0]), new Point3D([200, 100, 0]), new Point3D([200, 200, 0]), new Point3D([100, 200, 0]));
```

The points are not floats as you can see.

Comment: Could you provide an image with the white line you are seeing? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an artefact due to antialias or something similar on both edges. Not sure.

Comment: i added the image of it :)