# How to remove unwanted white lines that appear between the shapes in canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

Hi i have just render some canvas rect with proper x and y values. since i have found some white lines between the each rect. which disturbing the whole structure. please refer the attached screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQtx.png)

or Refer this also

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518178/js-canvas-white-line-between-2-objects?rq=1)

Issue Reproducing Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20.5, 20.5);
ctx.arcTo(20.5, 20.5, 100.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 20.5, 100.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 70.5, 20.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(20.5, 70.5, 20.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100.5, 20.5);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 20.5, 180.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(180.5, 20.5, 180.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(180.5, 70.5, 100.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 70.5, 100.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please run this source code and see a minute white line get appear between the two rect. (if it not visible 'zoom' the screen to see it clear)

Comment: The quality of your answers would improve with source code, with an image people can only speculate, and not find the actual line of code that needs to be changed.

Comment: Hi Wayne, i have attached the source code. please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I'm guessing it is an antialias issue, allowing the background to be slightly visible on the edge of the boxes, the background being white or appearing white in this case, (looks like it may be cyan from the first box being drawn to fill the canvas).

The fix to stop antialiasing is context.translate(0.5,0.5); Implemented as in:

```
context.beginPath();
    context.translate(0.5,0.5);

    context.moveTo(125, 20);
    context.lineTo(125, 230);
context.stroke();
```

results in no antialiasing and hard edges.

Comment: hi wayne, thanks for your help, i thing this will work. but in SVG also i faced the same issue, for that i have find a very simple solution as adding the property 'shape-rendering' as 'crispEdges' to SVG tag. like wise is there any options to fix the issue in canvas.

Comment: My general solution is to draw the canvas at a higher pixel count then I render it in CSS. The benefit of antialias is it does not result in a stairway type of edge on diagonal lines, and on animation does not move pixel by pixel instead it renders subpixel values by antialiasing or mixing the color on the edges like what you would get with a photograph or video. <canvas id="foo" width="300" height="200" style="width:150px;height:100px"></canvas>

Comment: Why should an animation move pixel by pixel? Did you realize that JavaFX uses floating point coordinates and not integers?

Comment: mipa, Canvas renders pixel by pixel without antialiasing when translate is used because translate rounds the floating numbers to intergers. Translate is the best tool for animation; But, you can force rendering to antialiase by displaying a large cansas in a smaller space.

Comment: Where did you see OP are using `stroke`? It really seems they are using `fill()` instead, and the 0.5 ugly hack only works for strokes with an odd lineWidth (1, 3, 5, ...), but will have negative impact on any other stroke lineWidth and on `fill()` calls. (This is because `stroke()` does draw a line which center is at the actual coord.)

Comment: Kaiido, I don't see the source code just the image.

Comment: Kaiido, Real world experience and a Christian duty calls for kindness to be shown to people who don't fully understand the rules. But I believe, if the user can not post the code the answer can not be answered, in this case.

Comment: Then... vote to close instead of answering. Whatever your duties, your answer having 99% chances of being completely off (doing this image using `stroke()` method would certainly kill the browser and would require skills from OP that would also allow debugging of this issue) your kindness won't help anyone.

Comment: Kaiido, relax. If translate killed browsers they would not implement it, and it does solve anti-aliases problems, which the description of the problem and the image itself point towards. You can not replicate the supplied image with fills bunted up to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173740/discussion-between-kaiido-and-wayne).

Comment: Hi All, I have attached the source code please review it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try rectangle.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT)?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/SetRectangleStroketoColorBLACK.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have set the stroke width as zero, that line is not a stroke line. i need to remove that lines, not to color it.

Comment: The question is tagged [html5-canvas], not Java.